# Twitter bootstrap carousel with one big item and 5 small thumbnails inside it

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So basically what i need to achieve is this:

[image: bootstrap gallery]

One bootstrap gallery with 1 item displayed, scroll 1 item also but in the same time we can see the next images coming or the previous under this big image. We see 6 small size thumbnails witch are sliding along with the big image. The arrows should be place in the middle of everything not only the middle of the big picture.

I started with the default bootstrap carousel code but got stacked at this point. Any solution for this thing?

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="..." alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="..." alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        ...
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see where did you get stuck, the code you posted is just the defaul bootstarp code copied and pasted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending some couple of hours on this thing i managed to achieve [this](http://fiddle.jshell.net/paulalexandru/nqyLkjn7/show/) and i am very happy.

Here is my **html** code:

```
<div style="width: 400px; margin: 0px auto;">

    <div id="myCarouselBig" class="carousel slide">

        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <div class="col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/bbbbbb/fff&amp;text=1" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/CCCCCC&amp;text=2" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=3" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f4f4f4&amp;text=4" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/fcfcfc/333&amp;text=5" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f477f4/fff&amp;text=6" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarouselBig" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarouselBig" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <div class="col-xs-3" style="width: 20%;"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/bbbbbb/fff&amp;text=1" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-xs-3" style="width: 20%;"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/CCCCCC&amp;text=2" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-xs-3" style="width: 20%;"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=3" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-xs-3" style="width: 20%;"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f4f4f4&amp;text=4" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-xs-3" style="width: 20%;"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/fcfcfc/333&amp;text=5" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="col-xs-3" style="width: 20%;"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f477f4/fff&amp;text=6" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev" style="display: none;">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next" style="display: none;">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>

</div>
```

The **javascript** code:

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 10000
})

$('#myCarousel.carousel .item').each(function(){
    var next = $(this).next();

    if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');            
    }

    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

    for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {

        next=next.next();

        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }

        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
});

$('#myCarouselBig').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (event) {
    if (event.direction == 'left') $('#myCarousel').carousel('next');
    else {
        $('#myCarousel').carousel('prev');
        $('#myCarousel').carousel('pause');
    }
})
```

And the **css** code:

```
#myCarousel .carousel-inner > .next.left, #myCarousel .carousel-inner > .prev.right {
    left: 0 !important;
}

#myCarousel .carousel-inner .active.left  { left: -20%;             }
#myCarousel .carousel-inner .active.right { left: 20%;              }
#myCarousel .carousel-inner .next         { left: 20%               }
#myCarousel .carousel-inner .prev         { left: -20%              }
#myCarousel .carousel-control.left        { background-image: none; }
#myCarousel .carousel-control.right       { background-image: none; }
#myCarousel .carousel-inner .item         { background: white;      }
```

Here is the [jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/nqyLkjn7/).

<sup>**Note**: The snippet contains 2 bootstrap carousels, one with a big image and another one with 5 small thumbnails. The 2 carousels are linked togheter meaning that each time you trigger the main carousel, the other one will slide to left or right. As you already know, bootstrap don't supports 5 colums but i made a hack adding widh 20% to each picture even if first i've used the col-xs-3 class on it. In the css you can find a left: 0 !important condition. This is a hack witch I found out after I spent almost 3 hours and without it the thumbnails carousel effect will crash. Another hack that you don't have to miss is to add a background color to the items as i did in the css because in some cases the images could seem strange and if your items contains text that text might look bold. Currently if you press on the small images nothing will happend, but i have in plan to develop it in the next days and i will probably update this code with that also.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You could use the bootstrap guide, which goes through how to make the slider, and there is a little bullet point menu along with that guide, which you could change to images, instead of the bullet points.

Have a go at trying yourself first and then paste your actual attempt.